# How to read properties from anonymous types using "dynamic" variable

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0, anonymous-types, jsonresult

I had the cunning idea of using a dynamic variable to test the results of a method that returns an anonymous type - more specifically it returns a JsonResult, which as json looks like this

```
{ "newData" : [ 1120741.2697475906,
      826527.64681837813
    ],
  "oldData" : [ 1849870.2326665826,
      1763440.5884212805
    ],
  "timeSteps" : [ 0,
      4.8828124999999998e-10
    ],
  "total" : 2
}
```

I can read the JSonResult which will give me the anonymous type. Here's my code:

```
var jsonResult = controller.GetChangeData(1) as JsonResult;
dynamic data = jsonResult.Data;
Assert.AreEqual(2, data.total); // This works fine :)
```

But how do I get at "newData" for example? This code....

```
var newData = data.newData;
```

Gives me a System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator, but I don't know what to do with it to be able to just use it as an arry of doubles.

I tried casting it as a double[], but it doesn't work either.

As an aside, can I easily check if a property is defined on the dynamic?

Comment: What happens when you try this `data.newData.ToArray()`?

Comment: var data2 = data.newData.ToArray();   --- > 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray'  (tried with some casts too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `.ToArray()` doesn't work is that it's an extension method, and extension methods aren't available at runtime. That just means you have to call the function statically. Does `Enumerable.ToArray<double>(data.newData)` work?

You may need `Enumerable.ToArray(Enumerable.Cast<double>(data.newData))` depending on what elements `newData` actually has.

Comment: Yes! Enumerable.ToArray<double>(data.newData) does the job for me :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the properties of an instance of a dynamic type

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dyn);
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
{
  object val = prop.GetValue(dyn);
  var propName = prop.Name;
  var propValue = val;
}
```

where dyn is an instance of a dynamic object.

Comment: This was a helpful copy+pastable nugget of code, that I'm pretty sure is going to become an extension method at work...

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the JavaScriptSerializer class to parse the Json string into a dynamic variable?  Eg:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObj = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
var newData1 = jsonObj["newData"][0];
```

Comment: +1 for a working answer. The prob with this is since my json was in a JsonResult, I needed to Serialize it to a string and then deserialize it back into a dynamic, so less ideal.